# Google my business graph showing in red with this output REDUCE_PERCENTILE_99

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using the Google business api, suddenly the entire api request stopped, the graph shows this:
REDUCE_PERCENTILE_99

Any idea what does this means please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After research, I found that a [Reducer operation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies#reducer) describes how to aggregate data points from multiple time series into a single time series, where the value of each data point in the resulting series is a function of all the already aligned values in the input time series.

REDUCE_PERCENTILE_99: Reduce by computing the 99th percentile of data points across time series for each alignment period. This reducer is valid for GAUGE and DELTA metrics of numeric and distribution type. The value of the output is DOUBLE.

Comment: Thank you, yes this what I have also found on the google website, but I cannot work out why my API communications would stop speaking to the Google API because of this. All the graphs show red all over with this message. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I didn’t find information related about this use case and why the API suddenly stopped working and shows the graphs in red, I kindly suggest to open a support case with google my business, I found this URL to open a case https://support.google.com/business/contact/api_default also I kindly suggest to share with the support team all the details of this behavior, I hope this information is helpful for you